# git push to remote stopped updating

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

I set up my Ubuntu server on AWS. created a bare git repo. Used post-receive hook with following line.

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/laravel --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

I created a remote on my local machine to directly push my local repository to my server .
Every commit and push to remote was working well but suddenly it stopped updating my live website. i again modified my files in master repository, staged,committed and then pushed to remote. got success message but still files on server are not updated. git pull remote says every thing is up-to-date.
Please help me to solve this i am new to git.

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging. First, is your hook running? You can add a `touch /tmp/post-receive.lastrun` to record the timestamp when it runs. Assuming that it's running, log into the instance and run the command manually to verify that it's able to check out. If you're getting the latest source tree, then the problem is with Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of a touch, you can add your hook an `echo "test"` in order to check that it is running.

But also add an `ls -alrth /var/www/laravel` in order to check the ownership of that working tree.